Dataflow | Bigquery IO to use different project for billing
I have a dataflow in GCP environments with below setup -

dataflow_project - where the dataflow runs
data_project - where the data is stored
billing_project - where the BQ select should be billed

Currently, when I use BigQueryIO.read() method, the BigQeury job runs in dataflow_project which means dataflow_project gets billed for the query execution.
As per org policy, any BQ query must be billing to billing_project. How can I specify the billing project in Apache Beam's BigQueryIO.read method? Giving below my current implementation:
return pipeline.apply(
                "Read from BigQuery",
                BigQueryIO.read(
                                new SerializableFunction<SchemaAndRecord, MyClass>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public MyClassapply(final SchemaAndRecord input) {
                                        return RowMapper.getMyClassObject(input);
                                    }
                                })
                        .fromQuery(query)
                        .usingStandardSql()
                        .withMethod(BigQueryIO.TypedRead.Method.DIRECT_READ));


You could try https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/current/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.TypedRead.html#withQueryTempProjectAndDataset-
